# Converting double to string 1

Tags: c#

I'm new to C#, I'm currently making a calculator, I want to make a simple calculation but it doesn't work properly.

Here is the current line:

```
Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(A.Text)+Convert.ToDouble(B.Text)+Convert.ToDouble(C.Text));
```

Here is a sample output with 1.1 in every textbox:
1.1+1.1+1.1 = 33

Comment: So, you are new to C# and that certainly looks like C#. Why did you add C++ and VBA tags? They have nothing to do with your question. Furthermore, your question is not Windows specific, so that tag is invalid, too. Finally, you will get the same result when using MonoDevelop instead of Visual Studio, so again, invalid tag. Only C# is valid here.

Comment: Please read [faq] and [ask] a couple of times..

Comment: `Convert.ToDouble` uses the current culture. If that culture is German, then `.` is the group separator, and not the decimal point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not specifying the culture in your conversions. Most likely you have a German culture (or some other European one) which uses the dot as group separator, not as the decimal point. The result is that `1.1` is interpreted as `11`.

There are two solutions:

1. Enter your numbers in the current culture: `1,1` (Preferred)
2. Parse the numbers using the invariant culture:

   ```
   Convert.ToString(
       Convert.ToDouble(A.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + 
       Convert.ToDouble(B.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + 
       Convert.ToDouble(C.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
   ```

The first approach is preferred, because it will ensure that the user can always enter the numbers in its own culture. Forcing a certain culture on users is something that was acceptable 20 years ago, but not nowadays.

Comment: @ChristianEngelsborgNaumannH: Please see update to my answer.

Comment: @ChristianEngelsborgNaumannH: Accepting both at the same time is not possible. You would be unable to know what the user means when he enters `1.001`. It can be `1001` (if interpreted with German culture) or `1.001` (if interpreted with invariant culture).

Answer (score -1):

You need to caluculate the sum and then add the parts together.
String.Format is a nice way to concat strings.

```
double sum = Convert.ToDouble(A.Text)+Convert.ToDouble(B.Text)+Convert.ToDouble(C.Text);
string resultStr = String.Format("{0}+{1}+{2}={3}", A.Text, B.Text, C.Text, sum);
```

Answer (score -2):

You should assign your intermediate results to a double-variable first and then put it to a string, i.e.

```
double d = Double.Parse(A.Text) + Double.Parse(B.Text) + Double.Parse(C.Text);
```

Eventually you can just call

```
string result = d.ToString();
```

This is far easier.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt.aspx).